# Installing Xcode and iOS SDK Issue?

Tags: ios, xcode

I just recently downloaded `Xcode 3.2.6` for my computer. When I got it installed, I opened it up to find that the iOS SDK was not installed. Why? Do I have to download it separately? Is there a place for me to download it instead of re-installing Xcode?

I did some research, and saw this, but can not remember if I saw the `iOS SDK` to install. I think it only said `Xcode Toolset`.

[image]

Comment: Where did you find Xcode 3.2.6, a museum? The current version is 4.5.2. I recommend downloading the latest version.

Comment: Actually, NO, i have Mac OSX 10.6.8 , and that was the only option

Comment: Apple has ways of ... *persuading* ... developers to upgrade to the latest version of OS X. This may be another one of them.

Comment: Wel, can i download the New Version on Version 10.6.8? Also, could i just download the SDK separately, then implement it into the Xcode IDE?